# HelloJNI Android 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: stringFromJNI'

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I googled a lot for a solution for my problem but I have found anything that helped me.
I am an Android beginner and have problems with the HelloJNI sample from the Android NDK.

I work with Eclipse and put the `hello-jni.c` file as well as the `Android.mk` in the `jni/` folder of my Android project. Then I put the `Hellojni.java` file into the `src/` folder in a package. I can build the code with the `ndk-build` tool. So I get the `hello-jni.so` file which is put into `libs/armeabi`.

Everything seems to be fine. In the main activity of the Android project, I can create an object of `Hellojni` like `Hellojni x = new Hellojni();`. But when I try to open the function `stringFromJNI` like `x.stringFromJNI();` the error occurs which I wrote in the title of this topic.

Is there anything wrong? Unfortunately the source code of the project is on another computer so that it is difficult to put it here. But I could try to do that in case you need it to give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you load the library? `System.loadLibrary("libname");`

Comment: agree with @hotveryspicy, if also problem, you can try use:`System.load(path)`, the path must the full path like:`/data/data/your_package_name/lib/libname`

Comment: Actually I didnt made System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); myself. I it is already implemented in the Hellojni.java of the HelloJNI sample of the NDK. But anyway, it does not solve my problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the native library like this?

```
System.loadLibrary("hello-jni.so");
```

Comment: Hi, yes I made System.loadlibrary("hello-jni");

Comment: Actually I didnt make System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); myself. It is already implemented in the Hellojni.java of the HelloJNI sample of the NDK. But anyway, it does not solve my problem yet.